# suspend and hibernate not working after updating ubuntu 14.04 in amd processor laptop?

Tags: 14.04, suspend, hibernate, amd-processor

when I suspend my laptop then it will not open from there even I have to hard shut my laptop every time to reboot it, suspend and hibernate both are not working.
What is the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem of your drivers of graphic card so you can update it by following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-amdcccle-updates  
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

but this will work for AMD Radeon, you need to find out for your graphics driver, you can easily find these packages from synaptic package manager.